# How to check specific table is locked in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am executing below query to find the whether my temp table is locked.

```
show open tables where in_use > 0 and table = 'temp'
```

But it throwing below error :

> Syntax error near 'table = 'temp'

I have searched but unable to get the correct syntax. Can anybody help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Approach1: Simply execute command show processlist; or show full processlist; command and check if any query/table is showing locked in processlist.

Note: check from super user to check all running process on server.

Approach2: execute show engine innodb status; and you can check locking here...

Approach3: In mysql 5.6 onwards you can check it in information_schema db also.

Note: If you are using any gui tools like mysqladministrator then you can check all running process in this and easy findout if any table is locked....

Update:

As you want to get this by sql query, so you can use below query-

For all locked tables-

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE in_use>0;
```

To check specific table-

```
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE in_use>0 AND `Table`='your_table_name';
```

Comment: hi zafar, actually i want to check this from any sql query. I am writing a java code, in which i want to add lock on some tables. So before putting lock i want to check whether specific tables are already acquiring any locks. any idea how to do this?

Comment: One doubt i have . I have executed query 
SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE in_use>0 AND `Table`='x';

Then trying to lock table x which thrown

java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Any Idea about this behavior?

Comment: you are locking a table which is using in any transaction, so when mysql going to lock that table then getting already locked this called deadlock situation, in this case after a certain time either transaction got free lock and complete or rolllback....

Comment: yes, exactly. but show open tables query i mentioned returning empty resultset, means table x is not acquiring any lock right? 
Still then deadlock situation is occurring. I doubt any other transaction using table x. Is there any other possibility ?

Comment: try at the time when no other than you using db server, as may be when you are checking show open tables it will not show any lock as all queries are passing smoothly without locking but as you lock a table then some frequently executing transaction lock the table and you dont get lock...to check it when you are getting deadlock message then show show fullprocesslist command from super user and check running queries then you can find which query is locking that table...

Comment: and how this lock tables/unlock tables query performance depends upon the number of records in the table?